# Limit of $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{9}{x}\bigl(\frac{3}{(x+3)^3}-\frac{1}{9}\bigr)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have to determine the following:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{9}{x}\left(\frac{3}{(x+3)^3}-\frac{1}{9}\right)$$

I've got so far:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{9}{x}\left(\frac{3}{(x+3)^3}-\frac{1}{9}\right)= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{27}{x(x+3)^3}-\frac{1}{x}\right)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{27-(x+3)^3}{x(x+3)^3}\right)=\cdots$$

How to go on? I've got $\frac{\infty}{0}...$

Comment: Are you familiar with L'Hospital's Rule for indeterminate forms like $\infty^0$, $\frac{\infty}{0}$

Comment: L'Hopital's rule is unknown for us so far

Comment: The $x\neq 0$ is unnecesary.

Comment: It is redundant to write $x\ne 0$.  That's part of the definition of "limit".

Answer (score 3):

Just develop the nuumerator and you'll get 
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{-x^3 - 9x^2 - 27x}{x(x+3)^3}
=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{-x^2 - 9x - 27}{(x +3)^3} = -1
$$

Answer (score 1):

When you plug in $0$ to $x$, you see that the answer is $0/0$. You have to use L'Hospital's Rule, which says

$$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}.$$

This applies only to $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$.

Hence, you just need to take the derivative of the top and bottom until you get an answer that is either the answer or you can't use L'Hospital's anymore.

So let's take the derivatives of the numerator and denominator:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(27-(x+3)^3\right)= -3(x+3)^2$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x(x+3)^3\right) = x(3(x+3)^2) + (x+3)^3$$

So now we can just plug zero in!

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-3(x+3)^2}{3x(x+3)^2 + (x+3)^3} = -27/27 = -1$$

Comment: Please see whether I changed something I shouldn't. You can see how to use MathJaX [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Further, I believe your result for the derivatives is incorrect.

Comment: @IanMateus It is, fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $L$ = the limit in question, then use definition of derivative for $f(x) = \frac{3}{(x + 3)^3}$, then $L = 9f'(0) = 9\left(\frac{-9}{(0 + 3)^4}\right) = -1$.